# React Hook radio buttons in map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have a map function inside a map function where i need to get values from a radio button. but the problem is i need to select one radio button from a row but it would select all
Below is my code

```
<TableHead>
    <TableRow>
        <TableCell />
            <TableCell align="center">None</TableCell>
            {roleTypeProject.map(item => {
                return <TableCell align="center">{item.label}</TableCell>;
            })}
    </TableRow>
</TableHead>
<TableBody>
<TableRow key={item.id}>
    <TableCell>{item.label}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="center">
            <Controller
                name={`radio_${item.name}`}
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) => {
                    return (
                        <Radio                                                                   
                         {...field}
                         name={`radio_${item.name}`}
                         color="primary"
                         disabled={item.name === 'owner'}
                         value="none"
                         inputProps={{ 'aria-label': item.name }}
                        />
                    );
                }}
            />
        </TableCell>
        {roleTypeProject.map(p => {
            return (
                <TableCell align="center">
                    <Controller
                        name={`radio_${item.name}`}
                        control={control}
                        render={({ field }) => {
                        return (
                            <Radio
                                {...field}
                                name={`radio_${item.name}`}
                                disabled={
                                    item.name === 'owner' &&
                                    p.name === 'viewer'
                                        }
                                color="primary"
                                value={`${item.id} ${p.id}`}
                                inputProps={{ 'aria-label': item.name }}
                            />
                        );
                    }}
                />
            </TableCell>
        );
    })}
</TableRow>
```

So ive figured out my payload and all the only problem im having at the moment is that all radio buttons can be selected while i want one of them per row.
[image]

Comment: hmmm so is there a way around?

Comment: Your radio buttons all say `name="radio-button-demo"`, are you sure it's supposed to do that? Radio buttons work in groups, based on their `name`.

Comment: ive tried that sorry i did change this later to name={`radio_${p.name}`} . but its still the same.

Comment: Can you create a [mre]? Here or on codesandbox?

Comment: What is Controller?

Comment: @Hamidreza React Hook Form embraces uncontrolled components and native inputs, however it's hard to avoid working with external controlled component such as React-Select, AntD and Material-UI. This wrapper component will make it easier for you to work with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your scenario on the basis of your code snippet, not sure if the data structure is correct or the same as in your code (i combined both arrays in my code example, but you should get the idea). The problem in your code is, that you iterate `roleTypeProject` outside of the `<Controller />` while instead you should do it inside the `render` prop. This way there will be one field for each row which RHF can manage.

```
<Table>
  <TableHead>
    <TableRow>
      <TableCell />
      {columns.map(({ id, label }) => (
        <TableCell key={id} align="center">
          {label}
        </TableCell>
      ))}
    </TableRow>
  </TableHead>
  <TableBody>
    {rows.map(({ id, name, label }) => (
      <TableRow key={id}>
        <TableCell>{label}</TableCell>
        <Controller
          name={name}
          control={control}
          render={({ field: { value, ...field } }) =>
            columns.map(({ id, name: optionName }) => (
              <TableCell key={id}>
                <Radio
                  {...field}
                  checked={value === optionName}
                  value={optionName}
                />
              </TableCell>
            ))
          }
        />
      </TableRow>
    ))}
  </TableBody>
</Table>
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Basic (forked)]

Comment: this helps but the thing is 
<span>None</span>
    <span>Editor</span>
    <span>Viewer</span>
also comes from an api

Comment: this does give me an idea what to do 
but my header values ie . editor and viewer come from one api and i have to add none to it. then my rows value ie owner manager and user are from another api
at the moment i have got my payload what im stuck with is all radio buttons can be selected in a row where i was one of them to be selected.

Comment: Can you please add your actual data structure from your api calls to your question? Otherwise it's really hard to get your requirements.

Comment: for rows
0: {id: 6, name: "user", label: "User"}
1: {id: 5, name: "manager", label: "Manager"}
2: {id: 4, name: "owner", label: "Owner", }

for columns
0: {id: 11, name: "editor", label: "Editor"}
1: {id: 10, name: "viewer", label: "Viewer"}

Comment: ive updated the code i have.
Things ive got done:
My payload is read everything is setup 

Problems:
the only probelsm im having at the moment are that all radio buttons are turning on.

Comment: I've updated my CodeSandbox and my answer according to your updated data structure, please check it. The reason why all your `<Radio />` components in a row are checked is, because you're missing to set the `checked` prop for the `<Radio />` component.